# Oracle Index query is not working

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, indexing, subquery

I want to improve the performance of a simple query, typical structure like that:

```
SELECT title,datetime 
FROM LICENSE_MOVIES 
WHERE client='Alex'
```

As you can read in different websites,like [this](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys), you should make an index like that:

```
CREATE INDEX INDEX_LICENSE_MOVIES
ON LICENSE_MOVIES(client);
```

But there is any performance in the query, it is like it where "ignoring" the index.
I have try to use hints like [this webpage says](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_oracle_index_hint_syntax.htm).
And the query result like this:

```
SELECT /*+ INDEX(LICENSE_MOVIES INDEX_LICENSE_MOVIES) */ title, datetime 
FROM LICENSE_MOVIES 
WHERE client='Alex'
```

Is there is any error in this syntax? Why couldn't I appreciate any improvement?

Comment: Have you checked the execution plan to see whether it is using the index? It *may* be valid to ignore it. How big is the table, how selective is the index, which version of Oracle are you using, and have you tried gathering statistics to make sure the optimiser has all the info it needs to think the index is useful (if it actually is)?

Comment: Hello Alex, it's oracle v11. It looks like it using Index, a  INDEX RANGE SCAN , but it fetch same raws than TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID, but not sure if it is correct... The table is not big, 200K bytes

Comment: See execution plan for --+ rule hint, if it will show you index usage, then it's ok. Now, especially if create new table and there is a few row Oracle creates optimized plan, for example it can show you table full scan in EP.

Comment: Yes it show the index usage, but no benefice from it ..

Answer (score 4):

Oracle has a smart optimizer.  It does not always use indexes -- in fact, you might be surprised to learn that sometimes using an index is exactly the *wrong* thing to do.

In your case, your data fits on a handful of data pages (well, dozens).  The question is:  How many "Alex"s are in the data.  If there is just one, then Oracle should use the index, as following:

- Oracle looks up the row containing "Alex" in the index.
- Oracle identifies the data page where the row is located.
- Oracle loads the data page.
- Oracle processes the query and returns the results.

If lots of rows (say more than a few dozen) are for "Alex", then the optimizer is going to "think" . . . "Gosh, I need to read every data page *anyway*.  Let me avoid using the index and just scan all the data."

Of course, this decision is based on the available statistics (which might be inaccurate or out-of-date).  But there are definitely circumstances where a full table scan is the right approach, even when an index is available.

Comment: in true, the name "alex" is in a loop representing a possible value from a variable. So, you think there is non way to improve the performance of this kind of query?